# Is "義理" the proper term in this case?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, calligraphy

I have trained for 25 years with a local (European) Aikido master, but now I have to move, albeit temporarily, to another town, and I would like to give a gift to my teacher to represent the "debt" I have with him for all he taught me.

I also practice Shodo, so my idea was to make a scroll with the Kanji "義理" and give it to him before leaving.

I just want to add that I will keep practicing at another dojo in the place I move to, and that I may very well come back to my hometown in a year or so, just so that you get a complete picture.

My question: is "義理" appropriate here? If this is not the case what would you suggest?

---

I opted for "礼" in the end - thanks to everyone who answered or commented this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that 義理 "social obligation" is a neutral term when used to describe a fact, e.g. 義理のお父さん "father-in-law", but whenever it is intended to convey some sort of emotion, 義理 always has a negative (e.g. burdensome) connotation. (For example, 義理チョコ, the chocolate every woman is obliged to give to their male coworkers/boss for Valentine's day).

Either your European teacher doesn't understand enough Japanese to be irritated by that, or he does understand Japanese well enough to know that *you* don't understand enough Japanese. In either case, the intention of giving a gift *will* be understood.

Still, if I were to choose, I'd choose some concept/word/short phrase that I found particularly interesting/moving/profound and that has some connection with you personally, with Aikido, or with your teacher (or all three).

(Imagine for a second Aikido didn't have anything to do with Japanese. Would you give a beautifully written version of "debt" to your teacher?)

Comment: Thanks - what about "gratitude"? 礼?

Comment: Or maybe 恩 would be better?

Comment: Yes I think [恩](https://scontent-b-nrt.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/t1.0-9/10339591_568098119964742_3498546102916583086_n.jpg) is good, also how about [感謝](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOYjgMCL4wUFCYfUmAEOF4T01w5JZwzVvVK1ckxtVdIRELJ46l)

Comment: I agree that 恩 is much better. Still, I'd recommend going for something that you understand, rather than something you just looked up in a dictionary (or something that was recommended to you by someone else).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not sure I fully understand 恩 myself, so I would recommend 感謝 if you need to ask. Conversely, if you want to stick with debt please write it in blood.

Answer (score -3):

報本反始 seems the exact word, I think. It means something like "Thank you (teacher, parent or mother nature) for many things. I will keep practising."

Comment: Hmm... What's your source? Where did you get the translation?

Comment: Apparently, this can be found here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/idiom/%E5%A0%B1%E6%9C%AC%E5%8F%8D%E5%A7%8B/m0u/

Comment: @virmaior ええ、私も辞書などのページをいくつか見ましたが、どこも「天地や祖先など、存在の根本に感謝し」「自然や祖先の恩恵に報いる」とか書いてあるけど、「恩師に・・・」とか書いてないんで・・・

Comment: @Chocolate 当てるというつもりは一切なかったです。まず、無意味と思いましたが、それは熟語と気づいてびっきるしました。それだけです。